# T-SQL query for the following table definition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have four tables in my database, you can see examples with sample data below.

Table1 `tbl_ActivityName`:

```
id  empId   ActivityName    
---------------------------------------
1    20      30_20
2    21      30_21
3    22      30_22

4    20      31_20
5    21      31_21
6    22      31_22

7    20      32_20
8    21      33_21
9    22      34_22
```

Table2 `tbl_Monday`:

```
id  empId   ActivityName    Plan    Actual
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1    20     30_20            1.1    1.1
2    20     30_20            1.2    1.1
3    21     30_21            1.3    1.2
```

Table3 `tbl_Tuesday`:

```
id  empId   ActivityName    Plan    Actual
------------------------------------
1    22       31_22          1.2    1.3
2    21       31_21          1.3    1.2
3    22       32_22          1.1    1.3
```

Table4 `tbl_Wednesday`:

```
id  empId   ActivityName    Plan    Actual
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1    22       31_22          1.2    1.3
2    22       31_22          1.3    1.2
3    20       30_20          1.1    1.3
```

I tried to write a query for them, like this:

```
select 
    a.empid, a.activityname,
    b.plan, b.actual,
    c.plan, c.actual,
    d.plan, d.actual 
from 
    tbl_activityname a,
    tbl_moday b,
    tb_tuesday c,
    tbl_wednesday d 
where 
    a.activityname = '30_20'
    and b.activityname = '30_20'
    and c.activityname = '30_20'
```

However that didn't return my expected results. Here's the results I expected:

Expected result `forempid = 20 and  Activityname = 30_20 from tbl_ActivityName`

```
activityName    empid   Monday_Plan Mondat_Actual   Tuesday_Plan    Tuesday_Actual  Wednesday_Plan  Wednesday_Actual
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30_20            20      1.1           1.1          -             -       1.1         1.3
```

Expected result `forempid = 22 and  Activityname = 31_22 from tbl_ActivityName`

```
activityName    empid   Monday_Plan Mondat_Actual   Tuesday_Plan    Tuesday_Actual  Wednesday_Plan  Wednesday_Actual
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31_22               22          -           -          1.2            1.3               1.2            1.3
31_22               22          -           -           -              -                1.3            1.2
```

Why doesn't my query get these expected results?

Comment: and what have you tried so far? Please include your query and the problem that you are facing

Comment: Use the edit -link in the question, don't add code to the comments

Comment: What's wrong with your query?   What results does it give, and how is it different from what you want?

Comment: I edited your question to be in a better, clearer order. Please edit in the data you *did* get when running your query and explain the expected data, as well as clarifying why the actual output is insufficient for what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use OUTER JOINs so you still get results when there is no matching data in one of the tables:

```
select 
    a.empid, a.activityname,
    b.plan, b.actual,
    c.plan, c.actual,
    d.plan, d.actual 
from tbl_activityname a
left outer join    tbl_monday b
  on a.activityname=b.activityname
left outer join    tb_tuesday c
  on a.activityname=c.activityname
left outer join     tbl_wednesday d 
  on a.activityname=d.activityname
where 
    a.activityname = '30_20'
```